# How to config htaccess file to redirect link in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have the domain "**abc.com**"

Now I want to bring source code back to localhost for development.

In localhost I have also created folder "***abc.com***"

I configure all things are ok, I test website successfully in localhost by "**localhost/abc.com**"

But some in my content and my menu have the FIXED links like "**/category/cate1**". I edit this link like "**abc.com/category/cate1**" it will be OK but I can't edit it because after development I will upload to server again.

So my question is how can I access to **localhost/abc.com** and when click the link "***/category/cate1***" it will be redirect to

"**localhost/abc.com/category/cate1**"

NOT

"***localhost/category/cate1***"

Thanks for all answer

Answer (score 2):

I prefer migrating whole website as all wordpress permalinks are hardcoded into database. So it is better to migrate database for localhost to avoid broken URLs

Please Follow this:[Easy Migration Script](http://www.sagardevkota.com.np/blog/easy-wordpress-migration-script/)

Comment: Every my project I followed for this tutorial but in this time the customer did this website before and I can not edit any thing in there. So that why I need some suggestion about this. I am in temper about them because they make fixed link in like this. @@